# How to compile a rosjava package offline?

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I tried to compile a rosjava package without internet connection and it complained about not being able to reach "https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_bootstrap/raw/indigo/buildscript.gradle"

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. 

* What went wrong:

> Could not read script 'https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_bootstrap/raw/indigo/buildscript.gradle'. 

> github.com`

After that, I tried again with internec connection and it compiled. I would like to be able to code without internet connection. Is it possible? How?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226643/how-to-compile-a-rosjava-package-offline?/) by [Manuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/1917/manuel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2016-02-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-15**:
For that particular error you can work around it by either making sure that file is available locally (and updating the URL to it in your grade script), or by copy/pasting the contents of that file into your own Gradle script (essentially replacing the include. Not recommended).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks. That gave me an idea: always try to download URL, but keep a copy just in case. In build.gradle I changed  this:

```java
buildscript { 
  apply from: "https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_bootstrap/raw/indigo/buildscript.gradle"  
}
```

To this:

```java
buildscript {
    def f = new File("buildscript.gradle") 
    try{ 
    new URL("https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_bootstrap/raw/indigo/buildscript.gradle").withInputStream{ i -> f.withOutputStream{ it
```

So I keep a local copy, but if available, downloads from internet.

---

Originally posted by [Manuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/1917/manuel/) with karma: 36 on 2016-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0